# Capturing HTTP traffic with Fiddler

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, fiddler

I have a web application that I'm developing in IntelliJ Idea community version for which I'm trying to capture both incoming and outgoing http (not https) traffic with Fiddler. I'm deploying and running the application (.war) inside IntelliJ using the jetty-maven-plugin. I have been able to capture incoming http requests fine with Fiddler but cannot seem to capture requests from my application to an external web service.

I've tried setting the java proxy settings as described in the [Fiddler documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp) but to no avail. I added the settings in the 'VM Options' in the Run Configuration that I have set up for deploying the app and starting jetty like this:

[image]

I've also tried setting the proxy for IntelliJ directly under File --> Settings --> System Settings --> HTTPProxy like this:

[image]

I've also tried setting the properties programmatically  like this:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
```

None of these work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to the question, but I was able to get Wireshark working as an alternative to view the outbound traffic since it doesn't work as a proxy.